# Method that returns the average of array of integers

Tags: arrays

I am new to programming. This is my question:

1. Write a method that returns the average of the array of integers.
2. If the array is empty, method returns 0.

What I have done so far:

```
public double getAverage (int[] values) {

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : values) sum += i;
    return ((double) sum)/values.length;
}
```

Any one help me with the 2nd part please?

Comment: You're already using the length attribute. Read up on how if() works and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (values.length == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Before Computing average use this code to check if array is empty or not
because if number of elements is zero then you will get division be zero exception

Answer (score 1):

before you do anything check your array.

```
if (yourArray.length == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a division by zero error.

You can use the max function to make the minimum value you divide by 1.

```
return ((double) sum)/Math.max(values.length,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (yourArray.isEmpty)
{
    return 0;
}
```